# Explanation for congruences equality

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to understand [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1343427/160028) answer.

I don't understand why $(ay)^2\equiv 17\pmod{128}$ iff $y^2\equiv 1\pmod{128}$

Could you please explain it to me?

Thanks

Comment: because $a$ is the particular  solution of $x^2\equiv 17 (\mod 128)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have, 
$$a^2\equiv 17 \pmod{128}$$
hence if, $$y^2\equiv 1 \pmod{128} $$
then, $$ a^2y^2\equiv 17 \pmod{128}$$
i hope it is clear this way

Comment: but why would $a$ be a solution in the first place? The author claims that $x=ay$ is the solution

Comment: Oh, it's the author assumption - Thanks!